# Placeholders in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, placeholder

I am using this script : http://www.morethannothing.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/placeholder.js to get some placeholders into IE. Works a treat for input types of text and password.

But just does'nt seem to load for Text Areas. Does anyone know of a line of code I could add to that, or maybes a little bit of jQuery or JavaScript to execute to get it to load.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jQuery placeholder plug-ins are a dime a dozen, you may want to switch to one that supports `textarea`s directly. These all do: [place5](http://code.google.com/p/place5/) (mine), [jquery-placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder), [jquery-placeholder (2)](https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder)

Comment: Agreed. The placeholder plugins have been a great find and very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `$(':text[placeholder],:password[placeholder]')` use `$(':text[placeholder],:password[placeholder],textarea[placeholder]')`

Comment: You should never use `:text`, `:password` or any other of jQuery's made up selectors (if you can help it) because, instead of using the browser's *fast*, native selector engine, Sizzle has to do all of the work itself by iterating over – in this case – all the elements in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

For all inputs and textarea:
$('input[placeholder],textarea[placeholder]')

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > 0 )
    {
        $(function()
        {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            if(('placeholder' in input) == false)
            {
                $('[placeholder]').focus(function()
                {
                    var i = $(this);
                    if(i.val() == i.attr('placeholder'))
                    {
                        i.val('').removeClass('placeholder');
                        if(i.hasClass('password'))
                        {
                            i.removeClass('password'); this.type='password';
                        }
                    }
                }).blur(function()
                {
                    var i = $(this);
                    if(i.val() == '' || i.val() == i.attr('placeholder'))
                    {
                        if(this.type=='password')
                        {
                            i.addClass('password'); this.type='text';
                        }
                        i.addClass('placeholder').val(i.attr('placeholder'));
                    }
                }).blur().parents('form').submit(function()
                {
                    $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function()
                    {
                        var i = $(this);
                        if(i.val() == i.attr('placeholder')) i.val('');
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }


    </script>
```