# placeholder in IE doesnt work for passwordfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, watermark

I have a passwordfor with a required field validation. placeholder attribute doesnt work in IE and instead, validation is fired for the watermark text which is displayed as special characters.
I came across lot of suggestions like here
[Placeholders in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031544/placeholders-in-ie) and 
http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html that work for all textboxes except for password.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need solution for IE8 and previous as well? Or just IE 9 ?

Comment: sorry for delayed response.i got it fixed by adding jquery.placeholder-enhanced.min.js.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the same behavior. Extremely frustrating stuff. I tried overriding the default template by adding a ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Password.cshtml template that looked like this:

```
@Html.Password("", 
ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue,
new { 
    @class = "text-box single-line password",
    placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark})
```

The above worked when I did it for a String type (~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Password.cshtml) but not for password. So I downloaded the source for MVC4 and took a look. The only thing I could see that would make the password field  behave in a manner different from the input (TextBoxFor) field is that the format data is passed as a null into the underlying HTML generation code (see System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions, line 233, PasswordHelper function). But that's just a guess. I could never get the unit tests running to verify that assumption.

Until I find a solution, my workaround was to change my Razor code from this:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
```

To this:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { placeholder = "Password" })
```

That made the desired watermark appear for me. It's a kludge but what do you do?

Answer (score 1):

Josh - You are on the right track.

Instead of

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
```

Use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
```